# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 with array when reading data

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error, undefined, fatal-error

I am getting this PHP error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1
```

Here is the PHP code that throws it:

```
$file_handle = fopen($path."/Summary/data.txt","r"); //open text file
$data = array(); // create new array map

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle); // read in each line
    $parts = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line_of_text, 2)); 
    // separates line_of_text by ':' trim strings for extra space
    $data[$parts[0]] = $parts[1]; 
    // map the resulting parts into array 
    //$results('NAME_BEFORE_:') = VALUE_AFTER_:
}
```

What does this error mean?  What causes this error?

Comment: How sure are you that every line in your file has a colon in it?

Comment: do a `var_dump($parts)`. you'll probably find that the point you get that undefined offset, there is no `1` key in the parts array.

Comment: If it looks like all the lines have a colon, check for blank lines.

Comment: you just need to make sure that count($parts) == 2 prior to doing your assignment.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Change

```
$data[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
```

to

```
if ( ! isset($parts[1])) {
   $parts[1] = null;
}

$data[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
```

or simply:

```
$data[$parts[0]] = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : null;
```

Not every line of your file has a colon in it and therefore explode on it returns an array of size 1.

According to [php.net possible return values from **explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

> Returns an array of strings created by splitting the string parameter on boundaries formed by the delimiter.
>
> If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, **otherwise an array containing string will be returned.**

Answer (score 21):

**How to reproduce the above error in PHP:**

```
php> $yarr = array(3 => 'c', 4 => 'd');

php> echo $yarr[4];
d

php> echo $yarr[1];
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phpsh/phpsh.php(578) : 
eval()'d code on line 1
```

**What does that error message mean?**

It means the php compiler looked for the key `1` and ran the hash against it and didn't find any value associated with it then said `Undefined offset: 1`

**How do I make that error go away?**

Ask the array if the key exists before returning its value like this:

```
php> echo array_key_exists(1, $yarr);

php> echo array_key_exists(4, $yarr);
1
```

If the array does not contain your key, don't ask for its value.  Although this solution makes double-work for your program to "check if it's there" and then "go get it".

**Alternative solution that's faster:**

If getting a missing key is an exceptional circumstance caused by an error, it's faster to just get the value (as in `echo $yarr[1];`), and catch that offset error and handle it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373824/445131

Answer (score 4):

Update in 2020 in Php7:

there is a better way to do this using the [Null coalescing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) operator by just doing the following:

```
$data[$parts[0]] = $parts[1] ?? null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "PHP Notice", so you could in theory ignore it.  Change `php.ini`:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

To

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

This show all errors, except for notices.

Answer (score 1):

my quickest solution was to minus 1 to the length of the  array as

```
  $len = count($data);

    for($i=1; $i<=$len-1;$i++){
      echo $data[$i];
    }
```

my offset was always the last value if the count was  140 then it will say `offset 140` but after using the minus 1 everything was fine

Comment: Actually you want to change `<=` to `<` and don't minus 1 your `$len` variable.

Comment: Thanks for heads i realised it recently when working on another project

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be as below. You won't miss the values from 0 to n.

```
$len=count($data);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
     echo $data[$i]. "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:
`$parts = array_map('trim', explode(':', $line_of_text, 2));` 
You have ":" as separator. If you use another separator in file, then you will get an "*Undefined offset: 1*" but not "Undefined offset: 0" All information will be in $parts[0] but no information in $parts[1] or [2] etc. Try to `echo $part[0]; echo $part[1];` you will see the information.

Answer (score -1):

I just recently had this issue and I didn't even believe it was my mistype:

```
Array("Semester has been set as active!", true)
Array("Failed to set semester as active!". false)
```

And actually it was! I just accidentally typed "**.**" rather than "**,**"...

Answer (score -1):

The output of the error, is because you call an index of the Array that does not exist, for example

```
$arr = Array(1,2,3);
echo $arr[3]; 
// Error PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 pointer 3 does not exist, the array only has 3 elements but starts at 0 to 2, not 3!
```