# Message: Undefined offset: 1 Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

in view, I try to call kriteria and sub kriteria:

I try to call id_kriteria, nama_kriteria kriteria from tb_kriteria for tittle, and then I call id_kriteria, namasubkriteria for option sub kriteria
this is my view code:

```
<?php 
                    $index =0;          
                    for( $i =1; $i <= sizeof($subkriteria_); $i++){
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3"><?php echo $subkriteria_[$i][0]['nama_kriteria'] ?></label> // is my error
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <input type="hidden" name="status_pemeliharaan" value="1" class="form-control">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id_kriteria[]" value="<?php echo $subkriteria_[$i][$index]['id_kriteria'] ?>" class="form-control"> // is my error
                            <select class="form-control"  name="isi_kriteria[]" required>
                                <option>Pilih Sub Kriteria</option>
                                <?php $no = 1; foreach ($subkriteria_[$i] as $data)     { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>"><?php echo $data['namasubkriteria'] ?></option>
                                <?php  $no++; } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

this is my controller code:

```
function Index()
    {
      $data['data'] = $this->PemeliharaanModel->Get();
      if($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['level']=="1"){
      $id_merk = $this->uri->segment(3);
      $data['data'] = $this->PemeliharaanModel->Get();
      $data['kendaraan_'] = $this->PemeliharaanModel->GetKendaraan();
      // $data['kriteria_'] = $this->PemeliharaanModel->GetKriteria();
      $data['subkriteria_'] = $this->PemeliharaanModel->GetSubKriteria();
      $this->template->load('template', 'Saw/DataPemeliharaan', $data);
      }else{
        $data['error'] = 'Anda tidak dapat mengakses halaman tersebut.';
        $this->template->load('template', 'error', $data);
      } 
    }
```

and this is my model code:

```
public function GetSubKriteria() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_kriteria');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $krit = $query->result();
    $data = array();
    $index = 0;
        foreach($krit as $x){
            // $data[][] = array(
            //     'id_kriteria'           => $x->id_kriteria,
            //     'nama_kriteria'         => $x->nama_kriteria,
            // );
        $id_kriteriax = $this->db->where('id_kriteria', $x->id_kriteria);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tb_subkriteria');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $id_kriteriax = $query->result();
            foreach($id_kriteriax as $z){
                $idKriteriaKey = $z->id_kriteria;
                $data[$idKriteriaKey][] = array(
                    'id_kriteria'           => $x->id_kriteria,
                    'nama_kriteria'         => $x->nama_kriteria,
                    'id_subkriteria'        => $z->id_subkriteria,
                    'namasubkriteria'       => $z->namasubkriteria,
                    'value'                 => $z->value
                );
            }
            $index++;
        }
        return $data;
        // var_dump($data);
    }
```

but if I try this code, error Message: Undefined offset: 1

thx for your response...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 with array when reading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456325/php-notice-undefined-offset-1-with-array-when-reading-data)

Comment: which files your error occurred ? please upload with your complete error!

Comment: in my view, Filename: Saw/DataPemeliharaan.php

Line Number: 96, 99
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-3"><?php echo $subkriteria_[$i][0]['nama_kriteria'] ?></label>                                                                                   <input type="hidden" name="id_kriteria[]" value="<?php echo $subkriteria_[$i][$index]['id_kriteria'] ?>" class="form-control">

Comment: don't add code blocks in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a table column id as an index key, you shouldn't rely on `for()` loop to get the index value since it's not always have sequential value. You could use `foreach()` instead, adjust the model and view codes like below.

**model** :

```php
public function GetSubKriteria() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_kriteria');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $krit = $query->result();
    $data = array();
    $index = 0;
        foreach($krit as $kr_key => $x){
            $data[$kr_key] = array(
                'id_kriteria'           => $x->id_kriteria,
                'nama_kriteria'         => $x->nama_kriteria,
            );
            $id_kriteriax = $this->db->where('id_kriteria', $x->id_kriteria);
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('tb_subkriteria');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $id_kriteriax = $query->result();
            foreach($id_kriteriax as $z){
                // $idKriteriaKey = $z->id_kriteria;
                $data[$kr_key]['subkriteria'][] = array(
                    // 'id_kriteria'           => $x->id_kriteria,
                    // 'nama_kriteria'         => $x->nama_kriteria,
                    'id_subkriteria'        => $z->id_subkriteria,
                    'namasubkriteria'       => $z->namasubkriteria,
                    'value'                 => $z->value
                );
            }
            $index++;
        }
        return $data;
        // var_dump($data);
}
```

**view** :

```php
    <?php
    $index =0;          
    foreach ($subkriteria_ as $kr_key => $kriteria) {
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3"><?php echo $kriteria['nama_kriteria'] ?></label> // is my error
        <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="hidden" name="status_pemeliharaan" value="1" class="form-control">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_kriteria[]" value="<?php echo $kriteria['id_kriteria'] ?>" class="form-control"> // is my error
            <select class="form-control"  name="isi_kriteria[]" required>
                <option>Pilih Sub Kriteria</option>
                <?php $no = 1; foreach ($kriteria['subkriteria'] as $data)     { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $data['value'] ?>"><?php echo $data['namasubkriteria'] ?></option>
                <?php  $no++; } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thx for your respon is helpful, but i try your code, now show the error at the view, Error was encountered Severity: ilegal string offset 'value' blabla

Comment: and if i try to var_dump($data); this array is just show one subkriteria, not all subkriteria data show in the array

Comment: hi, I've updated the codes on line `$data[$kr_key]['subkriteria'][] = array(`