# Imagick will not catch Notices or Warnings

Tags: php, exception, imagemagick, try-catch, imagick

When a Notice or Warning occurs, the image fails. However, I am unable to catch the notice or warning.

```
<?php

    $image = new Imagick($resource);

    try {
        $image->setImageCompressionQuality("Should be a Number Here not String");
    }
    catch ( ImagickException $e ) {
        echo "This is a catch"; // should catch here but nope!
    }
?>
```

The code above should catch because of the string passed when should be INT. The **image fails** but catch does not execute. I still get this message:

***Notice: Use of undefined constant Should be a Number Here not String - assumed 'd' in /var/www/class.php on line 15
Warning: Imagick::setimagecompressionquality() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in /var/www/class.php on line 15***

I also tried ( Exception $e )

Comment: because that's just a warning/notice. It's NOT an exception. An exception would only occur if something actually `throw`s it.

Comment: @MarcB Ok, makes sense but the image output still fails so what is one to do?

Comment: don't pass in invalid options?

Comment: @MarcB Lol, yes. One would hope not, but when you do not have control of your parameter values then you've got a serious issue!

Comment: easy enough to test if the provided value is a number or not.

Comment: @MarcB yeah but the program has 20 to 30 methods that accept parameters and accepted values range so its possible but much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, you should also check return value of $image->setImageCompressionQuality and can hide notices with @.

But also you can convert notices in your code to exceptions like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373780/how-to-catch-this-error-notice-undefined-offset-0). It is interesting solution, but i dont recommend to follow it. Checking correctness is better.

Comment: Actually the return value of the method is always 1 even if it fails (aka a notice or warning) so that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the method doesn't throw an exception in case on invalid input. You should do something like:

```
$result = @$image->setImageCompressionQuality("Should be a Number Here not String");
if (!$result) {
    throw new \Exception('Operation has failed');
}
```