# php weird undefined offset error

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

In my php applicaiton I have the following code:

```
try {
    $ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()][$day] += $quantity;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    ~r(array(
        $ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()],
        $day,
        array_key_exists($day, $ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()]),
        $e->getMessage()
    ));
}
```

The `r()` function prints the following:

```
array(4)
    0   =>  array(4)
        0   =>  0.9
        1   =>  null
        2   =>  null
        3   =>  1
    )
    1   =>  3
    2   =>  true
    3   =>  Notice: Undefined offset: 3
)
```

How can I have an error on un undefined offset when the offset actually exists given the dump of the array and array_key_exists ?

Comment: Side note: How do you have a function name that starts with `~`?

Comment: @phpisuber01:  Not part of the name http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: ~r (REF) is a library for dumping stuff

Comment: Ha, you're right, very sneaky I didn't even consider that since its not assigned or evaluated. /dunce-cap

Comment: @RocketHazmat: the first element I am dumping is $ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()] which is an array whith the key $day=3

Comment: @Sébastien: Yeah, I just realized that.  It wasn't clear what the array dump shown represented.  I edited the question for you to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: thanks! it's killing me. It's telling me there is a bug and there is not at the same time!

Comment: How is your `catch` catching this?  It's a `notice` not an exception/error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Maybe he's defined a custom error handler, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373780/how-to-catch-this-error-notice-undefined-offset-0

Comment: @Barmar: What if the exception is in the error handler instead of in this code?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I just tested, and the error in the error handler will be reported by this code.

Comment: @Sébastien: If you are creating a custom error handler... can you show that to us?  I'm curious if that's where the issue lies.

Comment: found it, thanks to your notice clue ! The array is initiated only with keys 0,1,2 but the += somehow adds another one before the error is thrown, hence the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you were trying to *append* to a value that did not exist in the array.

```
$ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()][$day] += $quantity;
```

This is the same as writing:

```
$ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()][$day] = 
    $ordersIngredients[$userIngredient->getId()][$day] + $quantity;
```

So, what's happening is that PHP is trying to *read* the value at index `3`, but it can't.  That's what causes your *notice*.  Since it's only a notice, PHP treats the undefined index as `null` and keeps going.  It then adds `null + $quantity` to your array.

After finishing the line, it moves into your error handler and then to your `catch` block.