# Is there any way to notice E_NOTICE in php code?

Tags: php, exit, e-notices

I have a PHP script that needs to be executed for hours and hours and sometimes for some reasons (for example network problem while executing of a script which needs to be connected to internet ,etc...) the execution process stops for a while and does wrong thing(and it always causes a E_NOTICE while the process is going to wrong way)

My question is that is there ((any)) way to notice when there is a warning in your script?(And stop the whole script as well)

There is a Pseudocode for my question:

```html
    if( ThereIs(AnyWarning) ) {
    exit("Sorry! You have 1 E_NOTICE so we should stop script!");
    }
```

I hope you understood what i mean :)

Thank You In Advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @bassxzero this is actually custom error.I don't think this is what i meant or maybe I don't know how to use it.

Comment: For example : exit()  whenever file_get_contents(XXXXXXX): failed to open stream happened in the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch this error: "Notice: Undefined offset: 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373780/how-to-catch-this-error-notice-undefined-offset-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) this will be helpful for your requirement. you can exit or you can log error in it. or you can add logic if error/notice occurs in code redirect to error page.

```
<?php
/**
* Used for logging all php notices,warings and etc in a file when error reporting
* is set and display_errors is off
* @uses used in prod env for logging all type of error of php code in a file for further debugging
* and code performance
* @author Aditya Mehrotra<aditycse@gmail.com>
*/
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "off");
define('ERROR_LOG_FILE', '/var/www/error.log');

/**
* Custom error handler
* @param integer $code
* @param string $description
* @param string $file
* @param interger $line
* @param mixed $context
* @return boolean
*/
function handleError($code, $description, $file = null, $line = null, $context = null) {
    $displayErrors = ini_get("display_errors");
    $displayErrors = strtolower($displayErrors);
    if (error_reporting() === 0 || $displayErrors === "on") {
        return false;
    }
    list($error, $log) = mapErrorCode($code);
    $data = array(
        'level' => $log,
        'code' => $code,
        'error' => $error,
        'description' => $description,
        'file' => $file,
        'line' => $line,
        'context' => $context,
        'path' => $file,
        'message' => $error . ' (' . $code . '): ' . $description . ' in [' . $file . ', line ' . $line . ']'
    );
    return fileLog($data);
}

/**
* This method is used to write data in file
* @param mixed $logData
* @param string $fileName
* @return boolean
*/
function fileLog($logData, $fileName = ERROR_LOG_FILE) {
    $fh = fopen($fileName, 'a+');
    if (is_array($logData)) {
        $logData = print_r($logData, 1);
    }
    $status = fwrite($fh, $logData);
    fclose($fh);
    return ($status) ? true : false;
}

/**
* Map an error code into an Error word, and log location.
*
* @param int $code Error code to map
* @return array Array of error word, and log location.
*/
function mapErrorCode($code) {
    $error = $log = null;
    switch ($code) {
        case E_PARSE:
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_CORE_ERROR:
        case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $error = 'Fatal Error';
            $log = LOG_ERR;
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
        case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
            $error = 'Warning';
            $log = LOG_WARNING;
            break;
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $error = 'Notice';
            $log = LOG_NOTICE;
            break;
        case E_STRICT:
            $error = 'Strict';
            $log = LOG_NOTICE;
            break;
        case E_DEPRECATED:
        case E_USER_DEPRECATED:
            $error = 'Deprecated';
            $log = LOG_NOTICE;
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }
    return array($error, $log);
}

//calling custom error handler
set_error_handler("handleError");

print_r($arra); //undefined variable
print_r($dssdfdfgg); //undefined variable
include_once 'file.php'; //No such file or directory
?>
```